# Android App usage (usagestats) does not show entry of Overlay drawn app like Facebook Messagener Chat head

Tags: android, overlay, usage-statistics

I am trying to capture individual app events in android to get to know the amount of time spet in each app. Most of the time it works fine for regular apps but for app who's screen are drawn as overlay such as facebook chat heads NO entry is shown in usage stats.
Same is the case for *#*#4636#*#* ->  Usage statistics.

Please let me know if there is any way to get overlay app's details.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Practically they are just Views attached to the WindowManager (managed by a service). I don't believe you will be able to distunguish when chat heads are expanded/collapsed.

Comment: @Pawel agreed, these are views drawn and controlled from a service.  But there are no intents or  actions attached also. its tricky. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a way to detect that a user is interacting with an activity which is not in the foreground. You need to employ usage events rather than usage statistics. You require the same permissions as usage stats. But use:

```
UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService("usagestats")
UsageEvents usageEvent = usm.queryEvents(startTime, System.currentTimeMills());
```

Then retrieve the usage events by employing a loop like this:

```
while(usageEvents.hasNextEvent()){
UsageEvent.Event e = new UsageEvent.Event()
usageEvents.getNextEvent(e)
//key bit of code:
e.getEventType()
}
```

Then if you retrieve a result with the value of 7 then it means that a user is interacting with an app but it isn't in the foreground.